# HTML/CSS Emails with Outlook 365 - Can't get "list-style:none;" to work with bulleted lists

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I have an HTML/CSS email working great in all email browsers, except in Outlook 365 the "list-style:none;" attribute is being ignored. I have the style set external and inline.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: To take out the guesswork from this, open the email in Outlook 365 and use the browser's Inspect Element function to get an idea what happens to `list-style-type`, e.g. whether it is removed runtime or simply overridden by O365 using specificity. If it's overridden, there's a chance you can set a higher specificity (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity regarding this).

Comment: There is now a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63948158/8942566

Answer (score 0):

I am no html/css email pro, but what I have read is that by creating your css within the email and having it internal in the `head` tag, or having it inline in the specific `ul` or `ol` tag. Also, make sure that you are typing `list-style-type: none;` and not `list-style: none;`.

Here's a pretty good site that gives alot of information on writing/styling HTML emails: [Rock Solid Emails](http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails/)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately changing to "list-style-type: none;" made no difference with Outlook 365.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
list-style:none!important;
```

Comment: Just tried it with no luck. I appreciate the input though!