# Email template HTML remove bullet points from ul

Tags: html, css, email, templates

I am currently  trying to make some email templates to be send via an Email client (SendGrid in this case). After doing some research on how to create these templates I came to the conclusion that using regular **HTML** & **CSS** is not the way to go since Mail client preprocessors (Mainly Gmail & Outlook) strip almost all styles which have been applied that are not inline. However I still am having one Issue.

I can't seem to get rid of the bullet points using `List-style-type:` none even inline on the `UL` and on each `LI` tag. Anybody has experience on how to remove bullet points from `UL` or an `LI` when it comes to Email templates?

Comment: See this [link](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/752-can-we-use-ul-and-li-in-email)

Comment: @Pieter, Emailing templates is a curse word. As far as I know, you can create custom templates with SendGrid.  But you should just be able to remove the bullet points by targeting the `<ul>` and setting `list-style: none;`.

Comment: @AnureshVP, please don't just refer to content via links, as it can be removed at any time which leads to your link being broken.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine `list-style: none;` with a solution for Outlook, which is to conditionally push them away from sight, like so:

Put this in your `<head>` section:

```
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  <style type="text/css">
    li {
        text-indent: -3em;
    }
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
```

With list:

```
<ul style="margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;">
  <li style="margin:0 0 16px 30px;padding:0;">content</li>
  <li style="margin:0 0 16px 30px;padding:0;">content</li>
</ul>
```

Note that Outlook does not respect margins in `<ul>`, and others have defaults, so it is best to always reset margins and paddings and then apply margins (not padding) in `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `list-style-type: none;` to li element to remove bullet points.

To remove bullet from UL you can simply use `list-style: none;` or `list-style-type: none;` If still not works then i guess there is an issue of priority css. May be globally UL already defined. So best way add a class to that particular UL and add your css there. Hope it will works.

Answer (score 0):

You may add **list-style-type: none;** to ol, ul tags 
and to apply it forcefully you may add '!important'

e.g: **list-style-type: none !important;**

Answer (score 0):

If the normal CSS isn't working, then you can try to set an blank 1x1 transparent image as the list markers.

```
ul.a {
    list-style-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAA=');
}
```